# Having issue Propel Installation in Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, propel, symfony5, propel2

I'm using following command

```
composer require propel/propel-bundle
```

and getting the following error

Problem 1
- propel/propel-bundle[1.5.0, ..., 1.5.2] require symfony/framework-bundle ^2.8.2 -> found symfony/framework-bundle[v2.8.2, ..., v2.8.52] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (5.4.*).
- Root composer.json requires propel/propel-bundle ^1.5 -> satisfiable by propel/propel-bundle[1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle/issues/505 Good luck.

Comment: you should try to use https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2 which has symfony 5.x support. The error you get is pretty clear its not compatible with symfony 5.4 because it requires 2.8.x

Comment: @Cerad Im getting this error: The child config "database" under "propel" must be configured.

Comment: @SteveTech I don't understand how you could be getting a database config error if the package won't even install?

Comment: @Cerad as per your link: This Command composer require skyfox/propel-bundle "5.0.x-dev"

Comment: I see.  Typically you would update your question or even start a new one when you make that sort of change.  I remember using Propel 15+ years ago.  Nice library but if you look through the various github issues you can tell it's barely maintained.  I think you should look for alternatives for new projects.  If you are trying to maintain an existing legacy project then consider these sorts of error messages to be learning experiences.